# Oracle OCI Error: Segmentation fault (core dumped) when fetching 100000 rows

Tags: sql, c, oracle, oracle-call-interface

Using Oracle's OCI library in C, I am trying to fetch 100000 rows with a simple fetch query

```
char *query_3 = "SELECT id FROM idmap_id WHERE primary_id IN (SELECT id FROM idmap_id_1)";
```

Table `idmap_id_1` has 100000 rows. I ran following code for fetching

```
unsigned int key=100000;
char output[key][120];
sb2 output_ind[key];
ub2 output_len[key];
ub2 output_code[key];
OCIDefine *defnpp;

rc = OCIDefineByPos(stmt, &defnpp, errhp, 1, (dvoid*)output, 120, SQLT_STR, (dvoid*)output_ind, output_len, output_code, OCI_DEFAULT);

rc = OCIStmtExecute(svchp, stmt, errhp, key, 0, NULL, NULL, OCI_DEFAULT);
```

Function `OCIDefineByPos` works perfectly fine for 10000 rows but it gives `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error when I try to fetch 100000 rows.

Can anyone please help?

I have noticed that the fetch returns 98800 rows. It gives this `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error if i increase the fetched row count to 98801.

Answer (score 0):

You can not fetch more than 25000 records.

Comment: so, If i want to fetch more than 25k records what should I do?

Comment: @imran You need to add where condition in the second query(SELECT id FROM idmap_id_1) so that you will get less records

Comment: ok, and if I want 100000 records what approach should I take?

Comment: I think I am not clear with my question. If I cannot fetch more than 25k records then yes, I will add rownum <= 25000. But if i want all 100000 then what should I do?

Comment: It is Oracle limitation. If you satisfy with my answer then please accept my answer.

Comment: Just a bit more information. Is it a C specific limitation because I can get all rows in the SQL Developer

Comment: I got the same problem in VB6.0

Comment: You haven't explained why. Is that really an Oracle limitation - if so where is it documented? Isn't it more likely to be a problem with memory management and the size of the structures breaking some O/S limit? Do different platforms behave differently? E.g. Windows vs. Unix, 32-bit vs 64-bit, etc.?